# How to add button on toolbar

Tags: ios4

I have to add UIBarButtonItem on toolbar...Button should be rectangular in shape..and how i ll handle the click event on the button...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small tutorial for just doing that: [How to Make a Toolbar with UIToolbar](http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/how-to-make-a-toolbar-with-uitoolbar/150/)